# Creating a subscription in Stripe - I'm confused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I use stripe subscriptions for my users with one plan for, say, $10 per month for 100 API requests and that's a **standard** price. However, if the user has used 150 API requests, I charge them $10 + $3. For 200 and more requests it's $10 + $7.

Say, I've subscribed the user on October 9th. On November 9th the webhook event `invoice.created` will be called by stripe. So if the user has used 150 API requests, I have to add $3 more to the basic price (I can do that only within 1 hours according to Stripe documentation https://support.stripe.com/questions/metered-subscription-billing).

```
  if even.type == 'invoice.created'
    Stripe::InvoiceItem.create(
      customer: stripe_customer_id,
      invoice: event.data.object.invoice
      amount: 300,
      currency: 'usd',
      description: 'additional price'
     )
```

The questions:

1. Will the event `invoice.created`, indeed, be called on November 9th **for the first time**?
2. Will that additional price of $3 be added to the current invoice of $10 for October 9th-November 9th or will it be added to the **future** invoice for November 9th-December 9th? From the documentation it's not clear.
3. How do I add metadata to the **original** invoice of $10? I can add metadata to the additional invoice but in case the user has used less 100 API request I don't have to create the additional invoice at all, so I can't rely to the additional invoice.
4. It says

> Create any invoice items before your customer is subscribed to the
>   plan, and then create the subscription via an update customer
>   subscription call.

- but I subscribe the user once and forever on October 9th! How can I create an `InvoiceItem` before or on that (on October 9th) date if one month hasn't passed yet, and thus it's not known how many API calls the user makes (on October 9th the user has made, obviously, zero API calls)? I can only create `InvoiceItems` in 30 days because it's when I **know** how much to charge them on top on the $10! On October 9th I don't know that. Don't I understand anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time an invoice is created, you get the event `invoice.created` on your webhook. So when you subscribe a customer to a monthly plan on the 9th of November, you will get this event on the 9th of November, on the 9th of December, on the 9th of January, etc.

The first invoice for a subscription (generated when you create a subscription) is always closed immediately, so it is not possible to add an invoice item at that point. If that's something you want to do (for a setup fee for example) you need to create the invoice item **before** creating the subscription. That way it would get added automatically to the first invoice created when subscribing your customer.

In your case, you want to add fees to the next invoice based on the number of API requests your customer made during the month that just ended. So in the `invoice.created` event you need to detect whether it's a new month starting or the first one. If it's a new month, you then need to decide whether you have to add an Invoice Item to the user or not (based on the number of API requests).

You can't add metadata to the previous invoice from the month before. You just need to add the invoice item to the current invoice (for the month that is starting) and put a description indicating that the extra line item is for the consumption for the previous month.

Comment: `to a monthly plan on the 9th of November` - I subscribe a customer on **October** 9th. So the customer will pay for the subscription first - once they get subscribed, not after a month has passed?

Comment: Exactly, Stripe's subscriptions always charge at the beginning of the cycle. If you want your customers to pay only at the end, you need to put them on a trial first, that way the first invoice would be $0 and on the next one (on the 9th of November then) you could add your extra fee

Comment: so the first 2 answers are 1) no 2) no ?

Comment: 3) - but what if I don't need to create an InvoiceItem because the user hasn't used over 100 API calls? What can I do in that case?

Comment: You're correct 1 and 2 would be a no I think. You don't need to add "metadata" to the previous invoice. Always deal with the one currently created (for next month then). Otherwise just make your own invoice email template and use Stripe's invoices to **charge** the correct amount

Comment: For 3 if you don't need and Invoice Item, just don't create one, the event `invoice.created` will be sent, you answer with a `200` response code and an hour later the invoice gets paid

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that I do need to add metadata for my own purpose.

Comment: Then add the metadata when the invoice is created not a month after? https://stripe.com/docs/api#metadata

Comment: Do you mean to the invoice that's created when the user gets subscribed? It's already closed.

Comment: Then put your customer on a short trial like a few minutes, the first closed invoice is for the trial and you will get a new one for the new cycle after a few minutes that you can update